# How do I add specific elements of a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

So I want to add the 3rd value of the elements in a list of lists if the first and second values are equal. And if not, I want the non-equal ones to be added to my sum list.

```
first=[[1,1,5],[2,3,7],[3,5,2],[4,4,6]]
second=[[1,1,3],[4,2,4],[2,3,2]]
sum=[]

for i in ((first)):
    for j in ((second)):
        if i[0]==j[0] and i[1]==j[1]:
            sum.append([i[0],j[1],i[2]+j[2]])
        

print(sum)
```

so this gives me `[[1, 1, 8], [2, 3, 9]]` but I want `[3,5,2],[4,4,6],[4,2,4]` in my `sum` list too. How do I do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `collections.defaultdict` from the standard library.

The idea is to set your dictionary keys as a tuple of your first 2 elements and increment by the third. Then aggregate keys and values via a dictionary comprehension.

```
first = [[1,1,5],[2,3,7],[3,5,2],[4,4,6]]
second = [[1,1,3],[4,2,4],[2,3,2]]

from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

d = defaultdict(int)

for i, j, k in chain(first, second):
    d[(i, j)] += k

res = [[*k, v] for k, v in d.items()]

print(res)

[[1, 1, 8], [2, 3, 9], [3, 5, 2], [4, 4, 6], [4, 2, 4]]
```

---

Here is the equivalent solution without using any libraries, utilising `dict.setdefault`:

```
d = {}
for i, j, k in first+second:
    d.setdefault((i, j), 0)
    d[(i, j)] += k

res = [[*k, v] for k, v in d.items()]
```

Comment: Since this is Python 3, you could do `[*k, v]`. But maybe that's not appropriate at this level.

Comment: Well, this works perfectly well! But I don't want to use any libraries since we haven't seen those in my class yet. But thanks anyways!

Comment: `chain.from_iterable((first, second))` can just be `chain(first, second)` or `first + second`.

Comment: @AlexHall, Thanks for your suggestions, I have updated. Using `chain` here to avoid building a new list.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it without dictionaries or libraries:

```
first = [[1,1,5],[2,3,7],[3,5,2],[4,4,6]]
second = [[1,1,3],[4,2,4],[2,3,2]]
checked = []
sum = []

for n_i, i in enumerate(first):
    for n_j, j in enumerate(second):
        if i[0]==j[0] and i[1]==j[1]:
            sum.append([i[0],j[1],i[2]+j[2]])
            checked.append([n_i,n_j]) # Save the used index

# Delete used index
[first.pop(i[0]) and second.pop(i[1]) for i in reversed(checked)]

# Append non-used index
[sum.append(first.pop(0)) for x in range(0,len(first))]
[sum.append(second.pop(0)) for x in range(0,len(second))]

print(sum)
```

Returns:

```
[[1, 1, 8], [2, 3, 9], [3, 5, 2], [4, 4, 6], [4, 2, 4]]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for in the first place, because it is easier to do any mathematical operation like subtraction just by changing i[2]+j[2] with i[2]-j[2]